# Should this be a POST or a PUT

Tags: rest, http-verbs

So I know that PUT is idempotent, whereas POST is not.  Let's say I have an 'add to team' type  method.  If you're not already on the indicated team, you're added.  If you are on the team already, then nothing happens.

I'm thinking that should therefore be a PUT, not a POST, because whether I call it once or a million times, the result on the server is the same.  You're on the team.

Is this correct thinking, or am I still confused?

Answer (score 0):

To create a team it is a POST on the teamS resource. Something like below

```
POST http://myservices.com/teams/
```

To create a team member it is a POST on the team resource. Something like below

```
POST http://myservices.com/teams/98098LKJLKLKJ/
```

or

```
POST http://myservices.com/teams/98098LKJLKLKJ/members (recommended)
```

To update a team information it should be something like

```
PUT http://myservices.com/teams/98098LKJLKLKJ/
```

To update a team member information it should be something like

```
PUT http://myservices.com/teams/98098LKJLKLKJ/members/90JN998J98J/ (recommended)
```

OR

```
PUT http://myservices.com/teams/98098LKJLKLKJ/90JN998J98J/
```